# How to solve "rigid type variable bound by" error for RandomGen?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to generate some random numbers and new random number generators. I didn't get too far yet, but I ran into this error and I don't understand how to fix it.

My code is:

```
getGenerator :: RandomGen g => g
getGenerator = snd (next (mkStdGen 42))
```

The error I get is:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘g’ with actual type ‘StdGen’
  ‘g’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? I also tried switching RandomGen to StdGen but get the error:

```
‘StdGen’ is applied to too many type arguments
```

I see that mkStdGen creates a StdGen, but according to the wiki page StdGen is an instance of RandomGen. Is there a way to somehow convert a StdGen to a RandomGen? I'm really confused right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your declaration is more general than the actual definition. Your declaration claims that the type of `getGenerator` could be any type that implements the `RandomGen` class. Suppose I had such a type, `MyRandomGen`. Then I should be able to write something like

```
let v = getGenerator :: MyRandomGen
```

and have `v` be bound to a `MyRandomGen` value.

However, your actual definition is not that general. The value of `snd (next (mkStdGen 42))` is *always* of type `StdGen`, not an arbitrary instance `g` of `RandomGen`.

The solution is to be honest about what `getGenerator` evaluates to.

```
getGenerator :: StdGen
getGenerator = snd (next (mkStdGen 42))
```